# Turn csv single column w/ multiple variables into multiple columns w/ single variable

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn

I have columns in csv with multiple variables like this

```
col1
a, c, e, f
b, c, g, p
d, e, i, x
```

and I need to turn them into

```
a    b    c    d
1    0    1    0
0    1    1    0
0    0    0    1
```

for machine learning pre-process purpose. When I tried with LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder, returned wrong dimension warning.

```
# Creating an integer encoding of labels  
label_encoder = LabelEncoder() 
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(X)
```

What's the right one to process this?

Comment: So you only want to consider a,b,c,d and leave all the rest?

Answer (score 0):

use [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).

Demo:

```
In [192]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [193]: cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w+\\b', vocabulary=list('abcd'))

In [194]: X = cv.fit_transform(df['col1'])

In [195]: X
Out[195]:
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [196]: X.A
Out[196]:
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)

In [197]: cv.get_feature_names()
Out[197]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

---

if we don't use `vocabulary` - we will get one column for **each** unique word:

```
In [203]: cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w+\\b')

In [204]: X = cv.fit_transform(df['col1'])

In [205]: X.A
Out[205]:
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)

In [206]: cv.get_feature_names()
Out[206]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'p', 'x']
```

---

Source DF:

```
In [191]: df
Out[191]:
         col1
0  a, c, e, f
1  b, c, g, p
2  d, e, i, x
```

Comment: my vocab is much more complicated than abcd, does that mean I need to compile the entire list first?

Comment: @DatCra, only if you want to limit your output matrix with those values belonging to vocabulary. If you omit parameter `vocabulary` - you will have one column for __each__ unique word

Comment: Since I have multiple colmns and `fit_transform(df[['col1','col2']])` doesn't work. How can I combine and transform them back to the original df?

Comment: @DatCra, you've asked a question about "Turn csv __single__ column..." - this question has been answered. Please feel free to open a new SO question if you want to know how to do that for multiple columns. (also please provide a corresponding sample data set there)...